# ST_Length and ST_Distance not returning the correct results

Tags: postgis, st-distance

Result I am getting back from both functions is **0.04036905073196378**

```sql
--E Fletcher Ave and N 46th St 28.069239, -82.409880
--E Fletcher Ave and Lettuce Lake Pkwy 28.069303, -82.369511
--2.5 Miles or 4.02336 Kilometers or 4023.36 Meters or 402336 Centimeters
SELECT st_distance(st_geomfromtext('POINT(-82.409880 28.069239)', 4326),
                   st_geomfromtext('POINT(-82.369511 28.069303)', 4326));

SELECT st_length(st_geomfromtext(
        'LINESTRING(-82.409880 28.069239,-82.369511 28.069303)', 4326));
```

Comment: That is absolutely correct: you are asking for Cartesian measures using *degrees* as units! You want to dive into coordinate references, planar Cartesian vs. spherical/spheroidal algebra and the difference between PostGIS `GEOMETRY` & `GEOGRAPHY` data types - you will find dozens of questions related to this topic.

Comment: I hope you have already found how to do it, for example by using casts like `st_distance(st_geomfromtext('POINT(-82.409880 28.069239)', 4326)::geography...`